# Full page scrolling plugins (fullPage.js, scrollify.js, etc) prevents default mobile Safari UI behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile-safari, fullpage.js

On iOS devices, scrolling plugins like [Scrollify.js](https://github.com/lukehaas/Scrollify), [FullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js), and [OnePage-Scroll.js](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll) seem to keep Safari's address and navigation bars in place, instead of the way they typically minimize when the user scrolls the page.

Is there any kind of workaround for this? I understand that when those UI bars minimize, the inner viewport height is changed, and so the plugin would need to recalculate the height. Also, the UI minimizes during the scroll event, and maybe that's problematic for the scrolling plugin? Is there a way to maybe hide the UI when the scroll event finishes?

When you change the orientation of the iPhone from portrait to landscape, the bars disappear, but if you bring them back by tapping the top or bottom, they stay put when you scroll.

I'd really like to have that extra height!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any kind of workaround for this?

You can also use it without autoscrolling, but that might no be what you are looking for: `autoScrolling:false`.

If you are worried for the landscape mode, if you avoid using anchors and you load the page in portrait mode to then change to landscape, it won't show the top bar at all **on iOS at least**. Not the best solution, but it might help.

Personally I would recommend you to use the option `responsiveWidth` or `responsiveHeight` to change the behavior of the page on small screen devices and remove the auto scrolling and possibly have bigger sections.

In general, mobile browsers do not allow access to the top or bottom bars behaviors and there's no much developers can use to deal with them.

Comment: I don't think using scrollbar:true has any effect on the UI. And the way I've designed the page requires the autoscrolling functionality of the plugin, even on small screens. I feel like it must have something to do with how the plugins prevent the browser's default response to the touch events.

Comment: Right. `scrollBar:true` has no effect on iOS, it surprises me as it is actually scrolling the site, but well.

Comment: If you are worried for the landscape mode, if you avoid using anchors and you load the page in portrait mode to then change to landscape, it won't show the top bar at all on iOS at least. Not the best solution, but it might help.

Comment: And no, there's no proper way to deal with the bars apart from that. Browsers do what they want with it and there's no much control for us there.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that the UI goes away if you turn the device to landscape, but when the user goes to tap on the nav menu button at the top of the screen, they come back and stay put.

Comment: Yep, not the perfect solution.